# Multi Language implementation in MVC Razor

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, entity-framework-6

In my Project MVC Razor C# Entity Framework Code First. There are 3 languages. I am using resource file to fetch the value. This is working perfectly.

Now, I have another requirement to do the management of language Key's value. So in this way there will be a screen where Admin can do the changes by selecting the language from Dropdown and then selecting the key from dropdown. Then there will be an option to update the value for the selected Key.

Question: Should I continue using resource file for this requirement ?

or Kindly suggest

Comment: check [this link](http://afana.me/post/aspnet-mvc-internationalization-store-strings-in-database-or-xml.aspx) for internationalization, sorry by the way don't continue using resx files if you want to administrate the localization

Comment: As you are adding CRUD for translations I would suggest you switch to DB.

Comment: @SherifAhmed: Excellent Link: http://afana.me/post/aspnet-mvc-internationalization-store-strings-in-database-or-xml.aspx  But I am worried about how should I approach for changing the value.

Comment: for this issue .. the problem you going to face is not how to change that values ... but actually you gonna face a performance issues because of that ... you should consider also using some kind of caching mechanism to not fall in the performance problems... because each client using the application will get all the resources each time .. so consider that in the future